# Creating a custom forum, use tables, <ul> <li> <dl> <dt>, or divs?

Tags: html, css

I need to make stretchy columns and rows with borders to the lefts and rights of each column. If one column's row stretches more, the other columns in that row should stretch. I found liquid 2 column layout and 3 column layouts, but those are divs. I searched phpbb forums and found that their forums are made out of "ul" "li" tags, then there's always the table method... easiest way to go.

Which method to go for? SEO friendly (incase any of these choices may be opinionated).

Comment: Have you checked the JavaScript solutions (like jQuery, Dojo, etc.) available?? I am not sure of the question but it might help you if you check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a HTML `table` for a forum.

It's tabular data, so a HTML `table` is the correct element to use.

Remember, [HTML tables aren't evil](http://webdesign.about.com/od/tables/a/aa122605.htm), they just shouldn't be used for layout.

Comment: Agreed (+1) People like to look-down on tables, saying they are inefficient (code wise). And yet same people will spend hours on doing the same thing with 10 divs and 20 classes, just to reach the same end-result with more code in place and much worse cross-browser support...

For most cases, I guess its because they charge by the hour :)